# eclipse - how to change package explorer sorting order (don't want lexicographic sorting)?

Tags: eclipse

[image]

Is there a way I can have it:

Sonication1,
Sonication2,
Sonication3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't. Change naming if possible: Sonication01, Sonication02, ..., Sonication10, Sonication11 to get wanted order.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is possible but it is a long and manual process.

You can select the properties of the Java project and click properties. Then, go to Java Build Path and selecting 'Order and Export.' There, you would move the wanted file up and down using the buttons and clicking apply.

I hope that this would answer your question.